# jQuery ajax requests only working linear and not parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to set up a progressbar showing the progress of a long working task which imports a large CSV-File and pass to the database. I start the import process with an initial jQuery.ajax call and setting up a timeout to get the processed lines from these file in percent.

The problem is when I start the initial ajax-call, all other ajax-calls just wait to be executed until the initial call is done.

So this is my code:

```
var progress = false;
var update_progress = function() {
    if(progress) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?do=update_progress'
        },
        function(json) {
            // Something < 100
            if(json.perc !== undefined) {
                $('#progress').css('width', json.perc + '%');
            }
            setTimeout(update_progress, 1000);
        });
    }
}
var start_import = function(i) {

    // Setting progress allowed
    progress = true;

    // start the update in 1s
    setTimeout(update_progress, 1000);

    // start the database-import (20-30 seconds runtime on server)
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?do=start_import'
    },
    function(json) {

        // Import finished, disallow progressing
        progress = false;


        // Finally always complete: json.perc is 100
        if(json.perc !== undefined) {
            $('#progress').css('width', json.perc + '%');
        }
    });
};
start_import();
```

This is a bit confusing, because I thought that each call can work itself asynchronously. What is wrong?

Regards Tim

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not call `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`? This is the problem! The next call of the function `update_progress()` will happen after the callback from the previous AJAX call returned!

Comment: I used setInterval() instead of setTimeout(). The setInterval was set to 1000ms and when the first - start import request - was fired, each second there was another waiting request. If the first request was finished, al other requests started in the same time.

Comment: To the current script: calling the method start_import() will set up the timeout to call "update_progress" at first and then doing the $.ajax() Request While this request will be executed, one second later I expect to get another request for the status update. But it does not work.

Comment: @TIm Was the problem be with the virst version (with `setInterval()`?

Comment: My first version used setInterval() but there were the same problems. The init request took 15 Seconds to be fenished and in second 2, 3, 4, [...], 13 started a seperated update request. But all update requests executed, when the first request was finished.

Comment: You said on Monday... Really?

Comment: Much projects, sorry.